# Locked out of Plesk due to ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: authentication, plesk, hsts

I'm looking for help with Plesk Obsidian access. With HSTS enabled I was browsing the Tools & Settings looking for the reason why my cron jobs never send an email to the specified address, suspecting the Firewall.

Long story short, I entered some security setting and disabled something. I don't know what setting it was exactly. It was some simple UI with only a handful of options, where one original value was "(default)" and I changed it to my "domain.tld", which was available as a dropdown option.

As I clicked Apply (I know, don't ask me why) I got a warning in my browser "Your connection is not private". Now I cannot log in to Plesk any more.

Is there any way I can disable HSTS via SSH to gain access to Plesk? I still have SSH and FTP access to the server. Here's the warning in Chrome:

[image]

EDIT:
I already tried the Plesk repair utility and `plesk ext sslit` with no luck. The setting I changed must have assigned my web domain's SSL to Plesk itself. I don't know how to use `plesk ext sslit` to fix it. Getting pretty desperate at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone facing the same issue:

The problem was that I went to **Tools & Resources** > IP Addresses > and clicked on my domain's IP. There the setting allows you to assign "Default site". This is the one that needs to be empty in the setup I am using. And I found posts on the Plesk forum where people had the same problem, so I'm not alone in this and neither are you ;)

The resolution is simple once you stumble upon the solution. You just need to go to `https://yourwebsite.com:8443/` This is the unsecured login panel for your Plesk you've probably used during your first Plesk setup. There your browser will give you the option to **Visit Page** anyway. Click that and then you can log in and fix the setting in **Tools & Resources** > IP Addresses. Once you've cleared the "Default site" field and applied the setting, you can log out and hopefully, access to your usual secured Plesk login login panel will be restored.

Your particular issue may be something else, but at least you now know how to access Plesk despite ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID problem.

Comment: was in similar situation and your answer helped